# MYSQL Search results not showing In Order of Results By Their Name

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sql-order-by

This query works ok, but when it shows the results it shows them alphabetically, rather than with the searched results first.

Say I searched for Baby Diapers, It will show Baby Diapers but at alphabetic position B, rather than Baby Diapers being the first results shown.

Adult diapers
Baby diapers
Casual diapers
Disposable diapers

I would like the results to be like this.

Baby diapers
Adult diapers
Disposable diapers
Casual diapers

There are other relevant results being shown obviously So they all are found and displayed together.

How should i amend this query so that the Baby Diapers will be the first result amongst them all.

```
select * from TheTable WHERE MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ('$search') AND (`category`) LIKE '%$category%' AND (`genre`) LIKE '$genre%' ORDER BY `title` ASC LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, but when you ORDER BY a string, it uses alphabetical order, so it is working ok. Maybe you are looking for a different order

Comment: Yes i would like the results to display the searched results first rather than all the results in alphabetical order

Comment: Please share more details. What does "at alphabetic position B" mean? Can you share sample input data, and the expected output corresponding to that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want certain hits to come up first in your result set you need to fiddle with your `ORDER BY` clause. Try something like this:

```sql
ORDER BY `title` LIKE `Baby Diapers%` DESC, `title`
```

If the title starts with that string, the `LIKE` clause has a value of 1, otherwise a value of 0. So ordering by it in descending order makes the rows it matches come first.

Do keep in mind that FULLTEXT search works peculiarly when you don't have very many rows in your tables; it relies to some extent on word frequency, and when there aren't many words the frequencies can be distorted. This can be very confusing when you test your stuff with small datasets.

And if you use `ORDER BY ... MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$search')` you'll get the rows in order of FULLTEXT's quality of match, for what it's worth.

Beware SQL injection attacks.

(Notice that this business of the values `1` and `0` coming from expressions such as `title LIKE 'Baby Diapers%'` is a MySQL-specific hack. Other makes and models of table server work differently.)

Comment: Ok, i have tried ORDER BY `title` LIKE `Baby Diapers%` DESC, `title` However it produces the same results. - When i use SELECT *FROM TheTable WHERE `title` LIKE `%$title%` i loose search results due to it not matching the exact words if there are 2 or 3 words. - It seems that the MATCH search is only searching the 2nd word also.

Comment: That's not exactly what I suggested for what it's worth.

Comment: your correct, i apologise. i just put the ,`title` on the end of the query